# VW Bora V6 2005 - Sump Replacement Question

Tags: engine, vw, oil-pan

My sump cover has a huge hole and I'm going to replace it.

Can I take the cover off from underneath the car or does the motor have to be lifted to recover the sump cover?

Comment: I had to drop the pan on my '99 VR6 (Vento) and didn't have to lift the motor.  It's not exactly the same, but is _very_ similar.

Comment: @JPhi1618 why don't you convert this to an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The sumps on most if not all Volkswagen watercooled engines can be changed with the engine still in the car including the Bora V6.